# Cross browser vertical centering of text in anchor

Tags: css

I have the following JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JxXHE/

I would like to make sure that the text in the menu items is centered vertically, 8px from bottom & top in all of the supported browsers.
Here's the list of supported browsers:
IE7, IE8, IE9
FF 3.6 - FF 10.0.2
Chrome
Chrome (Linux - no version specified)
FF (Linux - no version specified)

I manage to get something very close, but every I found another browser that show it differently (a pixel to here / there). Basically I prefer not to use CSS hacks but if that's will be the last resort we'll use them.

Any assistance / ideas on how to solve it will be welcomed.

Thanks,
Nadav

Comment: @Andrew Jackman: He's asking about centering vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: Wow I totally missed that word... :p

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `line-height`.  Here is what I modified in your jsFiddle: (and here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JxXHE/3/))

```
.ContextMenuItem
{
    min-width: 180px;
    line-height: 27px; /* I added this */
}
```

Basically, you want to add the font-size (11px in this case) to the amount of vertical space (8px) times 2 (8x2=16, 16+11=27)

Unfortunately, this will only work for single line bits of text, otherwise it will cause a space in between multiple lines.

Comment: We've tried that already - we had the same height & line height however just chrome showed it correctly. All of the other windows browser showed it with 7px (top) and 9px(bottom). We didn't check the linux versions.

Comment: Have you tried not setting a height, and only setting a line height?